# How to get Workflow Rule in Maven's Mate

Tags: workflow, mavensmate

I'm trying to import my workflow rules from my org using Maven's Mate and I have got all my custom objects and in the `package.xml` i have the following:

```
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>WorkflowRule</name>
</types>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Via the GUI

MavensMate > Project > Edit Project

[image: MavensMate > Project > Edit Project]

Then on the Advanced Tab look for "Workflow" at the bottom of the drop down list.

[image: Advanced Tab > Workflow]

Then click on "Update Subscription"

[image: Update Subscription]

Then refresh your index

[image: Refresh Index]

You can go over to the Project Metadata tab to select specific workflows (or any other metadata) you want.

[image: Select Specific Metadata]

Finally when you are done click "Update Project"

[image: Update Project]

Answer (score 1):

believe you just need to say workflow instead of workflowrule in your package xml

```
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>Workflow</name>
</types>
```

here's a list of all metadata type names

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_types_list.htm

Comment: thanks for the link and I did paste it in my `package.xml` and when i refresh from MM I do not see the workflow in my project `<types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Workflow</name>
    </types>`

Comment: y dont u select the components via the mavensmate project ui : http://mavensmate.com/API/UI

Comment: I have already tried from mm ui and check the workflow components but do not see it pulls from my org and thought to give it a trying using project.xml